# Why you need to specify subnets in Application Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I'll start with describing the architecture of Application Load Balancer:

We have the Application Load Balancer, which contains a list of one or more *listeners*. Each listener is associated with one specific port and protocol, so that traffic incoming to the load balancer with this port will be handled by this listener. Then, each listener holds a list of *rules*. A rule specify conditions and actions - basically where to route traffic to. A listener also must have a default action which will be taken if no other condition is met. Usually, this action will be to route traffic to a specific *target group*.

A target group is a group of either EC2 instances, IP addresses, other Application Load Balancer, or Lambda function.

Furthermore, when you create an Application Load Balancer, it asks you to specify a VPC and list of 2 or more Availability zones, and for each to specify a subnet.

My question now is: Why does AWS asks you to specify this? As far as I understand, the target groups and the registered targets are where you specify the backend of the load balancer, so why do we need to specify the subnets in the ALB configuration?

### EDIT

After experimenting, I found that, if I have a EC2 instance running a web server in AZ 3 for example, and now I create a load balancer and selects AZs 1 and 2, then traffic will not reach the web server on AZ 3 until I add another AZ in the load balancer settings.

So if to accurate my question: If this setting of AZs in the load balancer settings means: these are the AZs in which the Load Balancer will send traffic to, in what scenario should I not choose ALL the availability zones there are?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: @Paolo, not really, it's not very clear.

Comment: What exactly isn't clear? What questions do you still have?

Comment: It's just very short and not very explanatory. You are welcomed to expand it and be more elaborative.

Comment: Take the answer of John Rotenstein as an example

Comment: What isn't still clear to you?

Comment: Your question was one, which I answered. It looks like you either don't understand what you asked or you didn't understand my answer

Comment: The load balancer can only route traffic to the availability zones you chose because in each of those zones it created a network interface. Without the network interfaces the load balancer cannot function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Application Load Balancer runs on Amazon EC2 infrastructure. Think of it as an Amazon EC2 instance with pre-loaded software, but you don't actually see the EC2 instance in your own account.

Instead, you will see the **Network Interfaces** where the Load Balancer connects into the network.

Traffic will come into your network through an Internet Gateway then route within the VPC to the Load Balancer. The Load Balancer will then determine a target to receive the traffic, and will send the request **via the Network Interface to the resource in the VPC**.

When such traffic flows through the VPC, it is subject to normal **Security Groups and Network Access Control Lists (NACLs)**. Private IP addresses will be assigned for each Network Interface used by the Load Balancer.

The Load Balancer instance runs in multiple AZs. If one AZ has a failure, then the Load Balancer instance in the remaining AZ(s) will continue to run. This is why the Load Balancer wants a **connection to the VPC in multiple subnets**.

**Bottom line:** While you might normally think of the Load Balancer as a "blackbox service", it is still just some software running on a virtualized computer that needs logical connectivity to the VPC, and it obeys all the rules of networking within the VPC.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're saying that when I choose several AZs + subnets, an instance of a load balancer will be provisioned in each AZ-subnet, for high-availability. But technically, if I choose for instance AZs 1 and 2, and I associate this Load Balancer with a target group with one target in AZ 3, the load balancer will not route traffic. So the choosing of AZs has something to do with the backend targets.

Comment: That seems correct. From [How Elastic Load Balancing works](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html#cross-zone-load-balancing): _"When you enable an Availability Zone for your load balancer, Elastic Load Balancing creates a load balancer node in the Availability Zone. If you register targets in an Availability Zone but do not enable the Availability Zone, these registered targets do not receive traffic."_

Comment: What I don't understand though is why does a load balancer instance can only route traffic to targets in its own availability zone?

Comment: @yoavklein because the load balancer can only route traffic in the availability zones in which it has created a network interface

Comment: Interestingly, [Network Load Balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/network-load-balancers.html#cross-zone-load-balancing) do seem to have the ability to deliver cross-zone traffic: _"By default, each load balancer node distributes traffic across the registered targets in its Availability Zone only. If you enable cross-zone load balancing, each load balancer node distributes traffic across the registered targets in all enabled Availability Zones."_

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, Actually it seems that Application Load Balancers have cross-zone  load balancing by default: _With Application Load Balancers, cross-zone load balancing is always enabled.

With Network Load Balancers and Gateway Load Balancers, cross-zone load balancing is disabled by default. After you create the load balancer, you can enable or disable cross-zone load balancing at any time._

Comment: Cross-zone load balancing will allow traffic to be sent to a different zone, but the "How Elastic Load Balancing works" quote suggests that targets will only receive traffic in zones that are 'enabled'. I suggest that you do some monitoring to ensure that all instances receive the traffic.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, one last question if you will: Is there a reason for me not to enable the load balancer in all the Availability Zones? Is there some cost consideration?

Comment: Ooh, interesting question! The [pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/pricing/) seems to be totally related to the number of connections and bytes processed. So, more AZs doesn't seem to cost any more. However, you might only want to add it to AZs where you have targets because the Load Balancer _might_ send traffic to an AZ, which then gets sent to a target in a different AZ. There is a 1c/GB charge for traffic between AZs, so this could cost money for no particular benefit. I'm not sure whether the Load Balancer is smart enough to avoid such behaviour, but, your choice!

Answer (score 1):

> why do we need to specify the subnets in the ALB configuration?

Because the load balancer itself requires physical network interfaces, which are created in the subnets you specify (one network interface per subnet).

Answer (score 0):

When you need ALB you must assign an IP address to it. A subnet is nothing more than a range of IP addresses. By placing an ALB inside a subnet, you define which range of IP you desire to be assigned to this resource.  Moreover, These subnets allow you to configure different [security layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/configure-subnets.html#subnet-security) regards the resource inside the subnet for traffic management.

Your target group is located in another subnet with a different range, whereas you can place your ALB in another subnet with a different range.

Comment: I wasn't asking about the subnet in which the load balancer's IP is in, I was asking about the AZs+subnets of the backend that it routes to.

Comment: Ahh, I think @john-rotenstein is answering the question